# Can we leverage Community Builder customizations in a Lightning Component?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community-builder

I am working on a proof of concept for a lightning component that will be available in the Community Builder. This component will become a part of a managed package so I would like to make it as flexible as possible. The community builder contains a lot of point-and-click customization like changing the color palette for a template, but my question is this:

From a lightning component that implements `forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes`, is there any way to access customization values from the Community Builder?

I can't find any documentation on that `forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes` other than you need to use it for your lightning component to show up. Additionally, it looks like the `app.css` file generated for the actual community does not use helper classes like `.text-primary` from Bootstrap but instead just drops color values into very specialized classes.

Thanks for any tips or links to documentation explaining this stuff! If we just drop in our own styles we will stick out like a sore thumb on the community page. Additionally, I know that we have the `.design` file to provide customization values, but I don't think that we can pull attributes from that file into the `.css` file and would have to instead use inline styling.

Answer (score 1):

S. I work for Salesforce, specifically with Community Cloud. Seth mentioned that you were looking for this. I'm making some inquiries on exactly what's available, but for Lightning in general, it uses the Lightning Design System's design tokens functionality. An example is here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_using.htm
I believe that the font & color values populated in the branding view of Community Builder will automatically propagate to a set of design tokens (so you should not need to define them). I'm working with the team that builds it to determine exactly what those tokens are. Stay tuned!

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the info on the token usage. I'll do some more digging around too and see if I can find any more details on the community builder specific tokens.

Comment: Got a few more details. Remember, these are all pending official documentation so things may change a bit. The current tokens for *all* of Lightning are listed here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_standard.htm

Note that not all tokens will be available in Community Builder. I've had luck with the following:
betaTokenActionColorText
betaTokenActionColorBG
betaTokenActionColorBorder
betaTokenActionColorDarkerText
betaTokenActionColorDarkerBG
betaTokenActionColorDarkerBGHover
betaTokenActionColorDarkerBorder
betaTokenLinkColorText
etc

Comment: Thanks so much for looking into this. I will give those tokens a try.